# Achieving full resolution with PowerVR SGX454 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, drivers, graphics, resolution

I have a Mini-PC with an ASRock AD2700B-ITX motherboard, which has an Intel PowerVR SGX545 on-board graphic chip. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it today.

Everything is working properly and is quite quick and responsive, except that the video resolution is too low. I cannot set it higher than 1280x1024. I have a BenQ G2220HD display, which is capable of 1920x1080.

Since both the graphics chip and the display are capable of higher resolutions, I assume this is a driver problem?

Comment: can you confirm this is not supported natively by ubuntu? I was gonna get this chip too. also this the graphic card should be SGX545. NOT SGX454 as you mentioned above!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer you got in your [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11876583) is correct: if X.org doesn't have a chipset-specific driver, it's going to fall back to the generic VESA driver, which may not support all of the functions of that graphics chip.

I looked in [the manual](ftp://174.142.97.10/manual/AD2700B-ITX.pdf) for that motherboard, and it is very sketchy on graphics issues. It claims "up to 1920x1200" but doesn't justify that with a video memory spec. Given the nature of the Atom and PowerVR, I'd bet it's taking a slice of system RAM for a video buffer, but I don't see anything in the UEFI section of the manual on configuring its size.

You could try forcing X to recognize the video RAM. Say `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-vesahack` and put this in the newly created file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    VideoRam 9000
EndSection
```

This tells X that there is 9 MB of video RAM, enough for 1920x1200 at 4 bytes per pixel. If X won't restart when you do that, try changing it to 6750 kB, for 3 Bpp. I don't hold out much hope that this will work, but it's a thing to try. If it doesn't help, remove `99-vesahack`.

Your best option may be to install a graphics card known to have good X.org support.

Answer (score 1):

I have that same motherboard / OS setup and I'm using the cedarview drivers. I achieve full resolution but performance in 2D isn't brilliant.

http://daily.siebler.eu/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-intel-cedarview-atom-n2000-und-d2000-serie/

#### quoting original article

> There is a ppa repository with drivers for ubuntu 12.04 at
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/cedarview/ubuntu/ With the following
>   steps, you can get accelerated X working with the Intel Cedarview
>   Chipset on Ubuntu 12.04:
>
> - Just add the repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/cedarview/ubuntu/ to your APT:
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sarvatt/cedarview
>   ```
> - Install the add-apt-key utility
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo apt-get install add-apt-key
>   ```
> - Install the Repository KE
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo add-apt-key 0x4c96de60854c4636
>   ```
> - Make apt-get update
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo apt-get update
>   ```
> - Make apt-get upgrade to verify that your system is up2date
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo apt-get update
>   ```
> - You can try to Add "video=LVDS-1:d" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT 
>     variable, if your don't see anything remove it... on one of my Systems
>     it's working, on a second device it doesn't.
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
>   ```
> - if you're using PAE kernel, remove it and install generic kernel
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
>   $ sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
>   ```
> - Install the cedarview drivers
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo apt-get install cedarview-drm libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver cedarview-graphics-drivers
>   ```
> - Change Option "AIGLX" to "Off" because 3D isn't working (default section)
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo vi /usr/share/intel-cdv/X11/xorg.conf.d/61-cdv-pvr.conf
>   ```
> - Update the Grub Bootloader
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo update-grub2
>   ```
> - Reboot the System
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo reboot
>   ```

Seems that the manufacturer doesn't really care much about releasing Linux drivers for this chipset, it is a shame, it is a good-ish machine.