# Forcing X to recognise video ram, saving the file 99-vesa file

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, resolution

So I was looking at a question about forcing X to recognise video memory to achieve 1080p resolution, however when I finished the following piece of code:

```
Section "Device"

        Identifier "Screen0"
        VideoRam 1048576

EndSection
```

I don't know what to do. I tried to exit and save it but it told me "File and location does not exist" or something like that. What do I do? How do I save it? 
Here is the post I was looking at for answers.

[Achieving full resolution with PowerVR SGX454 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37383/achieving-full-resolution-with-powervr-sgx454-on-ubuntu-12-04)